# Keras callback at each timestep

Tags: python, keras

I have a Recurrent network, getting a sequence in entry, with shape `(nb_seqences, seq_length, entry_size)` and I would like to trigger a callback at the end of each timestep.

I saw that keras can make callbacks trigger at the end of each `train`, `epoch` or `batch` but how can I trigger at each timestep ?

The goal is to monitor the evolution of a specific variable in the network, and its evolution during the sequence

Comment: This is not possible... The only thing you can do is put "return_sequence =True" in your LSTM , this outputs the states... and you can make them be an output of your model if you want... This is the only way I see